# Spring Batch: how to restart and rerun only skipped items

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Can I restart job and process only skipped items after I have corrected the mistakes in file? I'm reading documentation and not finding currently this possibility. You can restart job if it is failed, but I'm thinking restarting job after it has been completed with some skipped items. If this cannot be achieved with configuration, what would be good way to implement it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have done in a case similiar to yours, is to log each skipped item in a file.
Then I created a second job that load the file and process all logged items.